# pdf viewer for pyqt4 application?

Tags: python, pdf, qt4, pyqt4

I'm writing a Python+Qt4 application that would ideally need to pop up a window every once in a while, to display pdf documents and allow very basic operations, namely scrolling through the different pages and printing the document.

I've found the reportLab to create pdf files, but nothing about pdf viewers. Does anyone knows anything that might help. i was really hoping for the existence of something like the QWebView widget...

thanks in advance to all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [Poppler](https://github.com/danigm/poppler) library for that.

Answer (score 0):

A Python binding to poppler-qt4 that aims for completeness and for being actively maintained.
https://code.google.com/p/python-poppler-qt4/

Answer (score -1):

what about okular? It is a full app, but it can always be call from another app.

Comment: thanks, i had thought about that. the thing is i would like it to be a one block program, looking forward to bring the program to different platforms that might not have Okular installed.